# Java Class class as a generic doesn't work as expected

Tags: java

A simple question about Class and its generic semantics. Why doesn't the following code work?

```
Class<Serializable> s = String.class;
```

Java tells me that `Class<Serializable>` and `Class<String>` are incompatible. How can they be, when `String` is implementing `Serializable`?

Shouldn't generics allow exactly this type of things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because`Class<String>` is not `Class<Serializable>`. However `Class<String>` is `Class<? extends Serializable>`

Answer (score 3):

No, generics explicitly *don't* allow this kind of thing. The classic example is a collection class of some kind. If `ArrayList<String>` was a subclass of `ArrayList<Serializable>`, then you could write

```
ArrayList<String> astr = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Serializable> aser = astr;
aser.add(new Integer());
// This will throw ClassCastException!
String str = astr.get(0);
```

After this code, you have an ArrayList<String>() containing an `Integer` object -- clearly this is not good.